# What does [dynamic] do in HLSL

Tags: hlsl

Here's an example (this if() is inside of a for loop, which itself has the [unroll] attribute):

```
[dynamic]
if (n.x > 1.0f || n.x < -1.0f || n.y > 1.0f || n.y < -1.0f || n.z < 0.0f || n.z > 1.0f)
{
    break;
}
```

I've never seen this before, but I stumbled across this in a shader I'm trying to convert to glsl. Searches turned up nothing but the SM 5 dynamic linking ability. I looked at the available if() attributes, and there's only [branch] and [flatten] listed.

Comment: I've never seen this before either.  Is it possible that it's just a mistake, and the author meant `[branch]`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking...no way to know though. Thanks for your input, must have been a mistake, I guess the compiler just ignores it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Microsoft's reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313968(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

`dynamic` does not exist as a valid attribute. In this case, the compiler should have emitted a warning, stating that the attribute was unrecognized.

Comment: Ah, very good, thanks for the closure on this one. That is, if we can assume it's the same situation for PC..